# WorkerExtensions.csproj trying to access private feed

Tags: azure-durable-functions

WorkerExtensions.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source...

WorkerExtensions.csproj was trying to access our private feed, hence it did not have the permissions to do so encountered the above error.

How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Nuget.exe sources update -Name “xxpackages” -UserName xxx -Password token

by running the above command in the package console, I successfully managed to resolve this error.